# Simple Donate Form Extension - what is path for front end - joomla

Tags: civicontribute, extension, contribution-page, 4.6.8, simple-donate-form

This is with CiviCRM 4.6.8 on Joomla 3.4.3.

I successfully installed the Simple Donate Form Extension and it works from within CiviCRM Dashboard, ie, Admin menu settings, CiviContribute menu Test/Live. But, I am not able to make it live on the frontend of the website. I've created a new menu item with the `Menu Item Type` selected as `CiviCRM => Contribution Page => Simple Donate Test` to no avail. The default CiviCRM form continues to appear. There is little documentation on this other than just set it and forget it.

*Please advise.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to add: **?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/simple/#/donation** to the end of your URL. That was how I got it to work for me, although I am using Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give menu link like below.

**For test page** - /civicrm/simple?test=1#/donation

**For live page** - /civicrm/simple/#/donation